# ROS Connection in React Native Is Not Happening

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, rosnode

ERROR  Error in ROS connection: {"isTrusted": false, "message": "Failed to connect to /10.0.2.15:9090"}

````
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Ros, Topic } from 'roslib';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ChargeLeft = () => {
  const [chargeLeft, setChargeLeft] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const ros = new Ros({
      url: 'ws://10.0.2.15:9090',  // Replace with your ROS server URL
    });


    ros.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Error in ROS connection:', error);
      // Handle the error as needed
    });


    const batteryPercentageTopic = new Topic({
      ros,
      name: '/battery_percentage',
      messageType: 'std_msgs/Int16',  
    });

    const handleBatteryPercentage = (message) => {
      // Assuming the message.data is the battery percentage value
      setChargeLeft(${message.data}%);
    };

    batteryPercentageTopic.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Error in batteryPercentageTopic:', error);
      // Handle the error as needed
    });

    batteryPercentageTopic.subscribe(handleBatteryPercentage);

    const updateInterval = setInterval(() => {
      batteryPercentageTopic.publish();
    }, 30000);

    return () => {
      batteryPercentageTopic.unsubscribe();
      clearInterval(updateInterval);
      ros.removeAllListeners('error');
      batteryPercentageTopic.removeAllListeners('error');
    };

  }, []);

  const rem = Number.parseInt(chargeLeft);

  let textColor;
  if (rem <= 20) {
    textColor = 'red';
  } else if (rem <= 80) {
    textColor = 'yellow';
  } else {
    textColor = 'green';
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    chargeText: {
      color: textColor,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.chargeText}>{chargeLeft}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ChargeLeft;
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Make sure that machine 10.0.2.15 responds to `ping` command. You may look at [vue-ros-demo](https://github.com/ravijo/vue-ros-demo) for a similar application.